# product search with name or description or attribute - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship, e-commerce

New to Laravel. I have the following tables.

```
products (
 id
)

attributes (
    id,
   name
)

attribute_values(
    id,
    attribute_id,
    value
)


products_attributes (
    product_id,
    attribute_value_id
)
```

I can able to get the product details along with its categories attribute name and value with everything.(it has translations also) Now need to perform the search operation.

(variations is attribute_values)

```
 $products = Product::whereHas('variations', function ($query)  use($search_txt) {
                $query->where('value','like', $search_txt);
             })->get();


  $product= product::whereTranslationLike('name', '%'.$search_txt.'%')
           ->orwhereTranslationLike('description', '%'.$search_txt.'%')
           ->get();
```

written the query separately, Don't know how to make it work together.

Can someone help me out with an example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to group the translation set of conditions.

```
$products = Product::whereHas('variations', fn ($q) => $q->where('value', 'like', $search_txt))
    ->orWhere(fn ($q) => $q->whereTranslationLike('name', '%'. $search_txt .'%')
        ->orWhereTranslationLike('description', '%'. $search_txt .'%'))
    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, You can combine both the queries

```
$product= product::whereTranslationLike('name', '%'.$search_txt.'%')
           ->orwhereTranslationLike('description', '%'.$search_txt.'%')
           ->whereHas('variations', function ($query)  use($search_txt) {
                $query->where('value','like', $search_txt);
             })->get();
```

Please let me know, if it doesn't work

Comment: Partially working.. When I search with the product name or description its working . When I search with attribute value( like $search_txt is black) its not working.(when I search with attribute values like color or size it should return the products which has the attributes(same like name and description)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to find the value if any of the where statements succeed. The trick is to use the OR in all appending `where` statements like so:

```
$products = Product
        ::whereHas('variations', function ($query)  use($search_txt) {
            $query->where('value','like', $search_txt);
        })
        ->orWhereTranslationLike('name', '%'.$search_txt.'%')
        ->orwhereTranslationLike('description', '%'.$search_txt.'%')
        ->get();
```

This way you will find products matching a `variation value` or `name` or `description` like `$search_text`

Answer (score 0):

Now its working I changed like below.

```
$product = Product::with('variations')->whereHas('variations', function ($query)  use($search_txt) {
                $query->where('value','like', $search_txt);
             })->orwhereTranslationLike('name', '%'.$search_txt.'%')
             ->orwhereTranslationLike('description', '%'.$search_txt.'%')->get();
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).